# UIImagePickerController 3.0 takePicture function 

Tags: iphone

How can i use it takePicture method to programatically capturing image.I want to take picture after 5 sec or want to set a timer on camera.Is it possible ti take picture without press take button.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial on this here.

http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 0):

As of OS 3.1, you can definitely do this, using the `takePicture` method.  You can hide the normal camera controls with the `showsCameraControls` property.  So you can do exactly what you want, just set a timer or use some other UI, and then call `takePicture` in your timer callback.  The one confusing thing I've seen is that if you call it "too soon" when the image picker isn't quite ready it appears to fail silently.